# ARGeoAnchor giving me wrong coordinates in RealityKit application

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, realitykit

I am trying to add a GeoAnchor on the plane where I touch on the screen. I have set the ARGeoTrackingConfiguration as shown below:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        let session = arView.session
        let config = ARGeoTrackingConfiguration()
        
        config.planeDetection = .horizontal
        session.run(config)
        
        
        // Start listening for location updates from Core Location
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.onTap)))
        context.coordinator.arView = arView
        
       
        
        return arView
    }
```

In my coordinator I do the following:

```
 @objc func onTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        guard let arView = arView else {
            return
        }
        
        let location = recognizer.location(in: arView)
        let results = arView.raycast(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)
        
        if let result = results.first {
            
            arView.session.getGeoLocation(forPoint: result.worldTransform.translation) { coordinate, altitude, error in
                print(coordinate)
                let geoAnchor = ARGeoAnchor(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: altitude)
                let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: geoAnchor)
                let box = ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.3), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .green, isMetallic: true)])
                anchor.addChild(box)
                arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

The getGeoLocation function always returns the coordinates as -180 and -180, which is wrong. GeoAnchors are available in my area but I am not sure why they don't work.

```
In the documentation of arView.session.getGeoLocation it says "To succeed, this function requires an ARGeoTrackingConfiguration session with state equal to ARGeoTrackingStatus.State.localized".
```

I am not sure where I am suppose to set the ARGeoTrackingStatus.State.localized.

Any help!

Comment: Hi @MaryDoe, what GPS coordinates did your iPhone give out when you tested MapKit app, for example?

Comment: When I run my app on iPhone I get -180 and -180 when I call getGeoLocation function.

Comment: I meant real coordinates that you can read using MapKit (if you tested it).

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the `ARSession.currentFrame` to report a geoTrackingStatus of `.localized`. Then getGeoLocation will work.